# python string and integer comparison

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to print all the numbers until the given user input using while loop. Example:Enter:5  ==> 1 2 3 4 5 But the below program loops for ever.

```
user = str(input("Enter : "))
i = 1
while i < user:
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 4):

ummm `while i < int(user):`?

Comment: it would be better to do `user = int(input("Enter : "))` instead

Comment: @lejlot: in Python 2, use `int(raw_input("Enter : "))` instead. `input()` already calls `eval()` on the input, so it'd be returning an integer for input consisting only of digits in any case.

Comment: I wss just refering to the fact, that it is better to convert user to int once, than in the loop.

Comment: Just to be sure, there should be a try except ValueError so that the input is checked properly.

Comment: meh thats all sort of outside the scope of the OP's question imho ... (although good suggestions) ... there are several things that are questionable about this (eg if he wants a string why is he using `input` instead of `raw_input`, if he wants an `int` why is he explicitly casting to `str`, etc

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
try:
    user = int(raw_input('Enter: '))  # Cannot compare a string with an integer.
except ValueError:
    print('Input should be an integer!')

i = 1
while True:
    i += 1
    if i > user:
        break
    print(i)
```

**Note:** In your code, even if we were to explicitly declare the `input` as an integer it would still not quite work the way you want it to. This is because in your code the `while` loop stops once `i` is equal to `user` (as the condition is *while less than...* and will thus not print out the final value, `user`. I therefore modified it so it breaks at the point where `i` is greater than `user`, meaning that the last printed value will be equal to `user`.

Example previous output where `user = 5`:

```
1
2
3
4
```

And with the new code:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

It is however better to use a `for` loop here, if you are not set on using a `while` loop:

```
for i in range(1, user+1):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) in Python 2.x will try to evaluate what the user enters, it is equivalent to

```
user = eval(raw_input(...))
```

In this case, you are explicitly converting whatever is supplied to a string (with `str()`). In Python 2.x, strings always compare larger than numbers, so `i < user` is *always `True`*.

It is wiser to use [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) and convert to `int`. You can also simplify your code with a `for` loop:

```
user = int(raw_input("Enter : "))

for i in range(user):

    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing an int to a str and that is why you are getting an infinite loop. You should compare the same type of variables

`user = int(input("Enter: "))`

should work

Comment: in python2.7 input gives you back an evaluated version of the string (in this case an int... ) ,,, Im guessing the OP has some reason to cast it to a string ...(although no idea what that may be)